# GKE: Ingress for internal load balance does not work

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress

1. I have GKE cluster and created an internal load balancer as specified in the following document.
   https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/internal-load-balance-ingress
2. Used the same example as specified in the document.
3. The ingress is stuck in the creation mode. Here is the describe of the ingress.

```
kubectl -n test describe ing 
Name:             ilb-demo-ingress
Namespace:        test
Address:          
Default backend:  hostname:80 (10.12.3.20:9376)
Rules:
  Host  Path  Backends
  ----  ----  --------
  *     *     hostname:80 (10.12.3.20:9376)
Annotations:
  kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration:  {"apiVersion":"networking.k8s.io/v1beta1","kind":"Ingress","metadata":{"annotations":{"kubernetes.io/ingress.class":"gce-internal"},"name":"ilb-demo-ingress","namespace":"test"},"spec":{"backend":{"serviceName":"hostname","servicePort":80}}}

  kubernetes.io/ingress.class:  gce-internal
Events:                         <none>
```

4. How do I debug and resolve the problem

Comment: what is your gke cluster version?

Comment: This feature is in "beta stage" do you have access for beta products?

Comment: Version is 1.15. Okay. Just noticed it is in Beta. So, may not work as is?

Comment: Some GCP beta features requires previous access, but I've just confirmed that is not the case here. So, I've tried im my lab environment and it is working as intended. So please share the yaml files you are using. Also, please describe how the network was configured for the GKE cluster. As mentioned in the document, you need to [prepare](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/internal-load-balance-ingress#preparing_your_environment) the vpc and subnetworks before. It was done?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure L7 Load Balancing Add-On was turned on for your cluster in gcp.

Comment: Is it http loadbalacer that is listed in add-on?. If so, it is already enabled.